# Sorting a list of lists when not all the values exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, lambda

I am attempting to sort a list of lists but the inner lists have different lengths. For example:

```
version_list = [[1, 1, 2], [1, 0], [1, 3, 3], [1, 0, 12], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

In the cases where there is no third value, it can be assumed to be 0. I have attempted to use:

```
revision = sorted(version_list, key=lambda x: (x[2] if x[2] >= 0 else x[2] = 0))
```

since I know that

```
revision = sorted(version_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
revision = sorted(version_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

both work otherwise.

The desired result would be:

```
[[1, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 12], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 3, 3], [2, 0, 0]]
```

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show expected output?

Comment: Do you mean this `sorted(yourlist, reverse=True)`? I don't think you need to implement an anonymous function, Python natively supports what you're trying to do.

Comment: The output I'm looking for would be [[1, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 12], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2],  [1, 3, 3],  [2, 0, 0]]. sorted(list, reverse=True) doesn't give this result.

Comment: Although apparently using reverse=False works perfectly. Thank you, not sure how I didn't catch this use previously.

Comment: Oh, then just `sorted(yourlist)` should work.

Comment: Right, you just want `sorted(my_list)`, lists are sorted lexicographically.

Comment: @DoganAskan Only as long as negative values aren't involved. The fallback value is 0 so negative values should come before (not after as would happen without `key` in `sorted`).

Comment: `sorted(version_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can return a tuple in your `key` where the third value depends on the length of the sublist (using 0 if the sublist isn't length 3):

```
>>> sorted(version_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2] if len(x) == 3 else 0))
[[1, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 12], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 3, 3], [2, 0, 0]]
```

In case you want to sort on a specific index first you can shuffle the `x[0]`, `x[1]` and `x[2] if len(s) == 3 else 0` parts.

If you want it more generic you can also use an explicit function:

```
def padded(lst):
    desired_length = 3
    fallback_value = 0
    x = [fallback_value]*desired_length
    x[:len(lst)] = lst      # inserts list
    return x

sorted(version_list, key=padded)
```

However as noted in the [comments (Dogan Askan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702809/sorting-a-list-of-lists-when-not-all-the-values-exist/43702854#comment74450469_43702809), **if there won't be negative values** you don't need a `key`-function at all because list comparisons work (correctly in your sample case) even if the lengths differ:

```
sorted(version_list)  # no key function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? Is seems by default sorted will do exactly what you need.

```
sorted(version_list)
Out[103]: [[1, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 12], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 3, 3], [2, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In support of Allen's answer, Python's `sorted()` built-in function works using the Timsort algorithm under the hood which does exactly what you want it to do: put the elements with less sub-elements in each first, e.g. `[1, 0]` is placed before `[1, 0, 5]`.